# JSON PHP parsing search API

Tags: php, json

Alright, I'm using the Blekko search API:

http://blekko.com/ws/?q=hello+%2Fjson

how would I go about parsing it ?

I have no experience of parsing JSON from PHP, so I'd appreciate a little help, and the `json_decode()` docs failed to explain everything for me, particularly getting the data inside `RESULT`. :) You know, [ and ].

Could you help pointing me in the right direction ? :)

Thank you, you're all so helpful! :)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @CamilStaps That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: That's what I mean't, the PHP docs for JSON. I've revised that part.

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ Before asking be sure to do at least a bit of research

Comment: Do a `var_dump(json_decode($the_value))`. You can now see what kind of variable you have. From that point, you should be able to handle it yourself.

Comment: how would I deal with the data from dump ?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is .. http://codepad.viper-7.com/CiA8zj

Comment: They'res not any issue, but how do I read that dump output ?

Comment: See my answer. There code is there for you to pickup from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code to access the API.
You should enter your own error/unexpected results handling where i've left the comments.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://blekko.com/ws/?q=hello+%2Fjson');

if(!empty($data)){

    $data = json_decode($data);

    if(!empty($data->ERROR)){

         // Error with API response.

    } else {

        $data = $data->RESULT;
        if(empty($data)){

            // No results.

        } else {

                // Uncomment the line below to see your data
                // echo '<pre>' . print_r($data) . '</pre>';

            foreach($data AS $key => $val){     
                echo $val->short_host . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    // Failed to retrieve data.
}
```